# Updating Kivy's display - Part two

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

The following code displays and updates the kivy display using kv strings loaded with Builder.load_string(). It works just fine. My question is how to modify this code to define the Example class in python rather than using dynamic class defined in the kv string?

```
import kivy
import threading
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock,mainthread

kivy.require('1.9.0')

KV1='''
Example:
<Example@BoxLayout>:
    Label:
        text:'hello'
    Label:
        text:'world'
'''

KV2='''
Example:
<Example@BoxLayout>:
    Label:
        text:'hello world'
    Label:
        text:'good morning'
'''

@mainthread
def update(dt):
    try:
       vRoot = App.get_running_app().root
       vRoot.clear_widgets()
       Builder.unload_file('file.kv')
       vRoot.add_widget(Builder.load_string(KV2,filename='file.kv'))
    except BaseException as e:
       print (str(e))

def loop():
    Clock.schedule_once(update,5)

class MyApp(App):
      def build(self):
          return Builder.load_string(KV1,filename='file.kv')

vThread=threading.Thread(target=loop)
vThread.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   MyApp().run()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can always implement in pure python whatever you did using `kvlang`. However [`kvlang`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#concept-behind-the-language) is recommended for faster, cleaner, effort less (compared to that in pure python) designing pattern.

Here, first you can define your widget in `.py` then design it using `kvlang` as,

```py
Builder.load_string('''
<ExampleTwo>:
    Label:
        text:'hello world'
    Label:
        text:'good morning'
''')


class ExampleTwo(BoxLayout):
    pass
```

Or can code the whole thing using pure python (without using `kvlang`).

With this your modified code should look like,

```py
import kivy
import threading
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock,mainthread
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

kivy.require('1.9.0')

KV1='''
Example:
<Example@BoxLayout>:
    Label:
        text:'hello'
    Label:
        text:'world'
'''

KV2='''
Example:
<Example@BoxLayout>:
    Label:
        text:'hello world'
    Label:
        text:'good morning'
'''


Builder.load_string('''
<ExampleTwo>:
    Label:
        text:'hello world'
    Label:
        text:'good morning everyone'
''')


class ExampleTwo(BoxLayout):
    pass


@mainthread
def update(dt):
    try:
       vRoot = App.get_running_app().root
       vRoot.clear_widgets()
       Builder.unload_file('file.kv')
#       vRoot.add_widget(Builder.load_string(KV2,filename='file.kv'))
       vRoot.add_widget(ExampleTwo())
    except BaseException as e:
       print (str(e))

def loop():
    Clock.schedule_once(update,5)

class MyApp(App):
      def build(self):
          return Builder.load_string(KV1,filename='file.kv')

vThread=threading.Thread(target=loop)
vThread.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   MyApp().run()
```

Comment: I want to have the design in kvlang but define the Example class in python as I explained in my post. if you can provide a solution, please post a modified version of my code. I am just beginning using python and kivy and learning by example is the best approach.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: why did you create an additional class 'ExampleTwo' in both python and kvlang? can it be only one 'Example'

Comment: So that it doesn't overwrite the other class with same name.

Comment: Can the different kv-lang designs update the same class?